SharePoint 2013 : link to DispForm corrupt
I use a list in SharePoint 2013. Clicking on the title normally opened my DispForm which I customized to my own needs. In my absense someone deleted stuff and tried to restore it without success. When I click the title in the list I get an error message unable to find the default display form for list...
How can I get the link back to my customized DispForm.aspx?

There is no SharePoint 2015. Please choose between 2013 or 2016 ;)

15.0.0.4953 to be precise

So this is SharePoint 2013 as SharePoint 2016/2019/SE are 16.x.

thanks I didn't know that. 2013 it is.

Are you able to use SharePoint designer to connect to the site? If yes, you should be able to access your list and see the forms that exists.

I am not able to access SP designer. My employer is rather frigide with these kind of options.

You should be able to revert the customization:
List Settings > General Settings > Form settings > Use the default SharePoint form

(screenshot is from SharePoint Online but SharePoint 2013 should have similar option)
Source: How to set new default forms for a list?

Unfortunately I dont have an option Form Settings under List Settings. Maybe its not allowed on our network.
